# Transform a Single<List<Item>> to an Observable<Item>?

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming

## Goal

I get a `Single<List<Item>>` from a network request call. At the end, I would like to use those items either as a `Observable<Item2>` or a `Single<List<Item2>>`. I go from `Item` to `Item2` with `new Item2(Item item)`.

## What I thought would work

```
Single<List<Item>> items
    .map(Observable::fromIterable) // Single<List> to Observable
    .map(new Function<Observable<Item>, Observable<Item2>>() {
      // I don't really know how I can do it here
    })
    .subscribeOn(//.../)
    .observeOn(//.../);
```

I thought I could transform the types of the `observables` with `map`, so I do not quite get why the parameters of the second `map` are `Observable<Item>`s and not Item.
How could I achieve this properly?

Comment: I think you need to use flatMap.

Comment: @AluanHaddad that was it, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to convert `Single<List<Item>>` into stream of `Item2` objects, and be able to work with them sequentially. In this case, you need to transform list into observable that sequentially emits items using `.toObservable().flatMap(...)` to change the type of the observable.

For example:

```
Single<List<Item>> items = Single.just(new ArrayList<>());
items.toObservable()
            .flatMap(new Func1<List<Item>, Observable<Item>>() {
                @Override
                public Observable<Item> call(List<Item> items) {
                    return Observable.from(items);
                }
            })
            .map(new Func1<Item, Item2>() {
                @Override
                public Item2 call(Item item) {
                    return new Item2(item);
                }
            })
            .subscribeOn(//.../)
            .observeOn(//.../);
```

Or, using method references you can make this code even more simple:

```
items.toObservable()
            .flatMap(Observable::from)
            .map(Item2::new)
            .subscribeOn(//.../)
            .observeOn(//.../)
            .subscribe();
```

**To summarize:** if you want to change the type of `Observable`, use `.flatMap()`

Comment: Thank you! I was using `map` when I should have used `flatMap`.

Comment: Would there be a Rx way to change the type of `Item` to `Item2` and keeping a `Single<List<T>>` output? So I would have a `Single<List<Item>>` as input and would output a `Single<List<Item2>>`.

Comment: Yes, you can use `.toList().toSingle()` just after `.map()` (or just `.toList()` if you do not care about getting Single specifically).

Comment: Instead of `toObservalble().flatMap()` you could use `flatMapObservable()`

Comment: Cool! Thanks (: Didn't know that

Answer (score 1):

There some methods to do that:

```java
items.flatMapObservable(Observable::fromIterable).map(Item2::new).toList()

// or

items.toObservable.flatMap(Observable::fromIterable).map(Item2::new).toList()

// or

items.toObservable().flatMapIterable(Functions.identity()).map(Item2::new).toList()
```

The first one is the simplest.